# What is the Windows command for using git ls-files to copy modified files?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, command-line, git-ls-files

On a unix machine you can run:

```
cp $(git ls-files --modified) ../modified-files
```

To copy the modified files to another directory. I'd like to do this on the Windows command line. (This command doesn't work).

My question is: **What is the Windows command for using git ls-files to copy modified files?**

---

EDIT:

git version is: `git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0`

Clarification: The issue isn't whether the `git ls-files` command works or not - the question is how to pass this list of files into the copy command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I worked out:

```
for /F %I in ('git ls-files --modified') do set a=%I |  copy  %a:/=\% c:\temp
```